# How does Java Spring resolve @Payload annotation?

Tags: java, spring, http

I have a @RestController class. It has a method with the @RequestMapping annotation that accepts POST requests. The method header looks like this:

```
public void event(@Payload Car car) {}
```

Here Car is a class that I created myself. I created an instance of this class in this project so that the class knows how a car should look. But how does Spring resolve the @Payload annotation? I would like to know so that I can ensure that I'm sending the requests properly.

I.e. when sending the post request, should I convert the Car object to a json string and then add it to the request body as a parameter like this:

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(carJson,"UTF-8"))

I am trying to do it like this, but it seems that UrlEncodedFormEntity expects a list. So maybe I should not be converting the object to Json and instead adding the fields of the object to a list and sending it like that.

Comment: If your sender is java then, staying in the spring framework, you can use `RestTemplate` to send a `Car` object and have spring automatically serialize it to json.

Comment: Where does that annotation come from?